# Get the template my TFS Project Uses

Tags: tfs

Is there a way I can download and view the XML used to control my TFS Project?  NOTE: I do not mean the standard template in TFS, but what is actually on the project (they don't match on my Server).

I want to see how some of the custom fields were put together.

Answer (score 1):

Field definitions should be stored on the workitems themselves.  You can use the [Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da) to export the work item type definitions and explore from there.

Power tools here:

Comment: You can find the power tools at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da